# Why is my .blur() code only working on second blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input, when the user enters something, my script sends the info over to a php script, which returns whether or not the entered text can be used.

If the text can not be used, it disables the submit button and adds a class to the reult text.

The problem  have is strange, the ajax works, the result is returned, but the button disabling and adding of the class doesn't happen unless you focus and blur the input a second time.

Here is my code:

```
$('#alias').blur(function() {
if ($('#alias').val()) {
    var aliascheck = $('#alias').val();
    $(".aliascheck").load('checkalias.php?alias='+aliascheck);

    var result = $('.aliascheck').text();
    if (result.indexOf("Taken") != -1) {
        $('#shorten').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.aliascheck').addClass('error');
    } else {
        $('#shorten').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.aliascheck').removeClass('error');
    }
}
});
```

The code is live here: http://markhenderson.ws/dev/tmtmu/
To replicate the "taken" event, enter "taken" as the alias. Any thing else will return available.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: load is async. You should take the rest of the code into a callback or make the call synchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the code after the `.load` call into a callback function of the async call.

Something like:

```
$('#alias').blur(function() {
if ($('#alias').val()) {
    var aliascheck = $('#alias').val();
    $(".aliascheck").load('checkalias.php?alias='+aliascheck, function() {
        var result = $('.aliascheck').text();
        if (result.indexOf("Taken") != -1) {
            $('#shorten').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('.aliascheck').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $('#shorten').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('.aliascheck').removeClass('error');
        }

    });


}
});
```